# Plink in batch script

Tags: batch-file, plink

```
@ECHO OFF

SET filename=autoexec.bat

FOR /R C:\ %%a IN (\) DO (
   IF EXIST "%%a\%filename%" (

      SET fullpath=%%a%filename%
      GOTO break
   )
)
:break

ECHO %fullpath%
```

Will give me a path with `\\` in between. How to come up with only `\` in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are doing:

```
FOR /R C:\ %%a IN (\) DO ...
```

Try instead, replacing the `\` with `*`;

```
FOR /R C:\ %%a IN (*) DO ...
```

The value in the brackets is the file set that you want to loop through, an asterisk specifies ALL.

Comment: he wants root dir, reason for \

Comment: `for /R` tree's a drive. He wants to loop through all directories on his C: drive until he finds `%filename%` - where `%%a` will equal the directory it is in.

Comment: sorry, i just skimmed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
set filename=autoexec.bat
for /f %%i in ('dir \*%filename% /b /s') do set fullpath=%%i
```